# Intellij file template: how to set file name dynamically

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, velocity

I'm making a intellij template  MyClassController but I want to insert just MyClass as name because I need to create thousands with same pattern.

I tried

```
package ...
#set($BASENAME = $NAME)
#set($NAME=${BASENAME} + "Controller")
#set($OBJNAME = $BASENAME.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + $BASENAME.substring(1))
import ...
```

but if #set($NAME= ... ) is present filename popup is not showing.
BASENAME's value (that is "") became NAME's value so my file end being named "$BASENAME" or "$".

There's a way to force name popup to appear or rename file after file is generated?